# Первое непоследовательное число

Tags: javascript

В массиве могут использоваться любые числа, как положительные, так и отрицательные. Мне нужно найти первое непоследовательное. Массив [2,3,5] содержит непоследовательное число - 5. Вот что мне нужно вернуть по условиям. Иначе если массив содержит числа [2,3,4], то он последовательный. В этом случае нужно вернуть null. В массиве содержаться только числа. Где ошибка?

```js
function firstNonConsecutive (arr) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let sum = arr[i] + arr[i - 1];
    let subst = arr[i] - arr[i - 1];
    if ((sum < -1) || (sum > 1)) {
      return arr[i]; // возвращает непоследовательное число
    }
    else if ((subst < -1) || (subst > 1)) {
      return arr[i]; // возвращает непоследовательное число
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Что считается последовательным числом?

Comment: Во первых, дайте определение "последовательного числа"

Comment: 1,2,3 последовательные. 1,2,3,6 - 6 уже непоследовательное

Comment: @Эникейщик под описанный Вами алгоритм подойдет последовательность «1232123» например

Comment: Что-то определение в тексте отличается от определения в комментарии...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну да, так и должно быть. Только внезапно выяснилось, что последовательное число это что-то совсем другое :)

Comment: @Эникейщик да, я уже тоже обратил внимание :)

Comment: Потому-что оно не мое. Я вообще не знаю зачем искажают определение

Comment: В массиве могут использоваться любые числа, как положительные, так и отрицательные. Мне нужно найти первое непоследовательное. Массив [2,3,5] содержит непоследовательное число - 5. Вот что мне нужно вернуть по условиям. Иначе если массив содержит числа [2,3,4], то он последовательный. В этом случае нужно вернуть null. В массиве содержаться только числа

Comment: В общем, делайте как было написано в удаленном комментарии. Если нужно по возрастанию, то проверяйте не модуль, а саму разницу.

Comment: @Эникейщик так в моем коде я и проверяю разницу соседних элементов

Comment: Проверяете, да совсем не на то. Сумма вам для чего нужна?

Comment: @Эникейщик интернет говорит о версии, как было в вопросе...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i] - arr[i - 1] != 1)
    return arr[i];
}
return null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Несколько извращенный способ:

```js
function firstNonConsecutive(arr) {
  let result = arr.reduce((acc, num) => {
    if (Array.isArray(acc)) return acc;
    if (num === acc + 1) return num;
    return [num];
  })[0];
  return result === undefined ? null : result;
}

console.log(firstNonConsecutive([2, 3, 5]))
console.log(firstNonConsecutive([2, 3, 4]))
```